# ViewPager exception when resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, fragment

I have ViewPager and Adapter with Fragments.

It is working very good, but sometmies when I clicked "Home button" and after 20 minutes back to my app, app is crashed "nullpointexception".

Here is my code:

Main:

```
pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); getFragments();
pageAdapter = new AdapterArticles(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(extras.getInt("position"); 
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Fragment:

```
public static final FragmentArticle newInstance(RssItem item){

    FragmentArticle f = new FragmentArticle();
       Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
       bdl.putParcelable("item", item);
       f.setArguments(bdl);

       return f;
     }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState){
       View convert = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_event, container, false);

       TextView title = (TextView)convert.findViewById(R.id.title);
       TextView info = (TextView)convert.findViewById(R.id.info);


       Item item = getArguments().getParcelable("item");

       info.setText(item.getItemDate());
       title.setText(item.getTitle());


       return convert;
     }
```

Stack:

```
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.wm.ga/pl.wm.scroll.ActivityArticlesScroll}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at pl.wm.scroll.ActivityArticlesScroll.getFragments(ActivityArticlesScroll.java:132)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at pl.wm.scroll.ActivityArticlesScroll.onCreate(ActivityArticlesScroll.java:69)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
02-04 10:05:53.545: E/AndroidRuntime(19517):    ... 11 more
```

I check that in this code is problem:
It is class that I have data, but when activity is resumed and I use getFeed, it is null.

```
public class ArticlesManager {

     private static ArticlesManager instance = null;
     private HashMap<String, RssFeed> feedMap = new HashMap<String, RssFeed>(); 

        private ArticlesManager() {

        }

        public static ArticlesManager getInstance() {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = new ArticlesManager();
             }
             return instance;
        }

        public RssFeed getFeed(String name) {
            RssFeed rssFeed = feedMap.get(name);
            return rssFeed;
        }

        public void addFeed(String name, RssFeed rssFeed){
            feedMap.put(name, rssFeed);
        }

        public void clear(){
            feedMap.clear();
        }

        public void clearArticle(String name){
            feedMap.remove(name);
        }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: In which line you are getting `nullpointexception` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your extras might be null OR getInt("position") might be null. Post your full stack trace so that we can understand what is happening. Also you should provide the full code of your activity or Fragment where you are getting those Extras.